# Google reCAPTCHA V3 version, receiving "browser-error" response to the user who access the page from iphone Safari browser, what could be reason??

Tags: iphone, safari, recaptcha, recaptcha-v3

In our web application, we implemented & using google reCAPTCHA V3 version.

For some of our end-user (mostly occurs to iphone safari browser end-user) we receive "error-code" : as "browser-error" response part of CAPTCHA responses instead of captcha-score.

In google reCAPTCHA documentation, they asked to re-try the execute() of client end captcha call. As this error occurs if there is client side network issue / timeout issue.

We tried to simulate the issue (of our end-user) using iphone safari browser (for same browser version) we couldn't re-simulate it.

What would cause above error still ? to some of the end-user ? how to resolve it ?

Thank You.

Tried in similar iphone - safari browser, but it's working fine as expected.

But end-user / customer experiences the issue.